# Wrong type argument: stringp, nil error

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need to use `update-directory-autoloads` function in a little el-script. When I'm trying to call this function with an argument that is a name of a directory I receive this error:

`Wrong type argument: stringp, nil.`

Call looks like this:
`(update-directory-autoloads "~/test")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generating autoload files is poorly documented.  You're experiencing the problem that arises because you haven't set the variable `generated-autoload-file`.  Try the following:

```
(let ((generated-autoload-file "~/test/loaddefs.el"))
  (update-directory-autoloads "~/test"))
```

Update the `generated-autoloads-file` binding to be the location where you want the `loaddefs.el` file to live.

Comment: Thank you. The problem really was in generated-autoload-file undefined.

Answer (score 11):

When you get `Wrong type argument: foo, bar.`, you should `M-: (setq debug-on-error t) RET` and then reproduce the error so as to get a backtrace.  Actually, you can set `debug-on-error` like that in your .emacs and Emacs usually stays perfectly useable.

Comment: `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` is a bit nicer for the interactive case.

Comment: Indeed.  Or even "Options => Enter Debugger on Error" in the menu.